# How many characters / glyphs can be assigned to webfonts?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using this web app for generating custom icon fonts: http://icomoon.io/app/#font

For the purpose of this question, I need to be able to assign each icon to a character that can be entered into html.  So far I have used a-z, A-Z, 1-0(plus shifts), and then alt+1-alt+254 (for all of the remaining ones not used by the previous).

I have 404 icons the need to be represented and this leaves me about 70 short.

Are there other ways of inputting characters that I am missing?

Comment: You should use Private Use Areas in a Unicode font; those are plenty big to contain whatever you need. Don't overload defined alphabetic characters with nonsense symbols.

Comment: Is there any reasonable way to see the hex decimal codes for the puas all listed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833657/how-many-characters-glyphs-can-be-assigned-to-webfonts#comment26029139_17833657) mentioned in his comment on your question, *Private Use Areas* are what should be used for custom symbols.

From the very first paragraph of the [Wikipedia article about Private Use Areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_%28Unicode%29):

> In Unicode, the Private Use Areas are three ranges of code points (U+E000–U+F8FF in the BMP, and planes 15 and 16) that, by definition, will not be assigned characters by the Unicode Consortium. They are intentionally left undefined so that third parties may define their own characters without conflicting with Unicode Consortium assignments. Under the Unicode Stability Policy, the Private Use Areas will remain allocated for that purpose in all future Unicode versions.

You shouldn't overwrite existing Unicode characters. If your custom font failed to load for whatever reason it would fall back to a default (defined by your site or the browser). In this case, your webpage would be filled with random gibberish where the pre-existing Unicode characters you had overwritten are now displayed.

Comment: That makes sense, but how can I see how to display these puas in html?  I can't seem to find a list of their hex values anywhere.

Comment: All I can find are websites like this: http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/private_use_area/1  that would require clicking and loading 400 individual pua pages to see their hex codes for html.  There surely has to be somewhere where these are all listed on one page.  I just don't know how to find it.

Comment: @fender It's pretty simple: use HTML entities of the notation `&#xHHHH;`, where `HHHH` is the hex code for the code point. `&#xE000;` is the HTML entity for the character at code point U+E000.